# Вывод времени в чат в соответствии с временной зоной

Tags: php, javascript, время, timezone

Как реализовать вывод времени в чат в соответствии с временной зоной?
Пробовал на js временную зону записывать в куки

```
var TimeZone = Dates.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.cookie = "TimeZone="+TimeZone;
```

а потом в php записывать в чат время по UTC и приводить такие манипуляции

```
date("d.m.Y H:i:s", time() + ($_COOKIE['TimeZone'] * -1) * 60 * 60);
```

Но нужного результата не получил, у меня нормально, а у некоторых не правильно показывает.

**Обновление**

`date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` дописал это в файл перед отправкой смс в бд, после вывожу, но браузер не вереводит в нужную дату, при выводе код выше не использую.

Comment: при выводе времени - оно выводится локальное по умолчанию. Так что передавайте в utc, при выводе браузер сам переведет, а еще лучше unix timestamp

Comment: вы водите сразу на php? я говорил про клиентскую сторону: получили от php unixtimestamp - сделали new Data(time) - вывели полученное значение - получили локальное время